# Showing div based on checkbox value with Javascript and style display attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have created a web form with ASP.NET MVC.

I have successfully setup my **View** to  add the checkbox which shows a div based on its value on click. This is the functioning Javascript:

```
$('div.schedule .input_control').click(function () {
  var $target = $(this).closest('div').find('.showSchedule');
   if (this.checked) {
      $target.show();

   } else {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to exclude this schedule?") == true) {
        $target.hide();
        $(':hidden').not("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val('');
      } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
      }
   }
});
```

Here is the HTML snippet that has checkbox and div to be hidden and shown:

```
<div class="schedule">
   @Html.CheckBox("schedule", false, new { @class = "input_control" })
   <div style="display: none" class="showSchedule">
      //form fields
   </div>
</div>
```

The div is shown and hidden successfully when the checkbox is ticked and unticked by clicking on it. The confirm message works as expected too.

**But** when there is a validation error and form page loads again the **div is hidden** while the **checkbox ticked**!

How can I ensure that the div is shown always based on the value of checkbox? This is important as when the item is edited the form loads with the checkbox ticked but the div hidden.

I realize this would be because by default, my div style is set to "display: none".

So what is a better way for this?

Comment: Do you have a live example we could look at? You could always use a script to `display` the item with `show()` (`jQuery`) at a `DOM` load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function to check the checkbox is checked or not on document ready, if it's checked then show the div, otherwise hide the div

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input = $('div.schedule .input_control:checked');
    var $target = $input.closest('div').find('.showSchedule');
    $target.show();
});
```

Comment: Ok yes. But it seems that I have to add this in another JS file or embed it within the cshtml page. It doesn't work when I add this in the same JS file as in my question.

Comment: Also this works but it shows all the divs with schedule class. I want only the div to show that contains the checkbox. The line:  var $target = $(this).closest('div').find('.showSchedule'); and $target.show(); is what did the trick in my JS. But not sure how to implement it with your suggestion.

Comment: I've edited the answer, I think it's what you are looking for

Comment: Nice and Simple! Thanks!

Comment: But why can I not add this JS to the JS file from my question? It only works when the JS codes are in separate sources. How can I have both the JS in one source?

Comment: Ok is it ok to surround this JS code and my one from question object with $(document).ready(function () { ....  });? It works that way.

Comment: They should be able to put on same file, move the click function to the document ready function in my answer